# Pass Nullable Int to Request.Form[] in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nullable, request.form

I have submit form in `View` where price fields can be null.
I get values in action with `Request.Form[]`:

```
int? min = int.Parse(Request.Form["min"])
```

but I get Exception when the field is null because null can't be parsed in int.

Anything else to try?

Comment: So if the value is zero (a valid integer) you want it to be null?

Comment: oops, missed that. thanks, I'll stick with another answer. or just replace `0` with `-1` maybe

Comment: OK, it changing `0` with `-1` didn't help. I'll try other answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test if the value is null before parsing

```
int? min = null;
if (Request.Form["min"] != null)
{
  min = int.Parse(Request.Form["min"])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert it to integer first, then I'd perform a check to see if it has to be NULL or not (as I assume your program relies on that).

```
    int i = 0;
    int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Request.Form["min"]), out i); // Convert textfield value
    int? min = (i > 0 ? (int?)i : null); // Determine whether we should take the original value or NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `int.TryParse` as shown :

```
int num1=0;
if(int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Request.Form["min"]), out num1))
{....}
else{....}
```

In above code `num1` will have the  required output,if conversion failed then `num1` will have value `0` otherwise value of `Request.Form["min"]` will be there in `num1`.